# Import large Data in Neo4j without knowing the node id

Tags: neo4j

I have a problem in witch is the best way to insert some data in neo4j db.
I have a file with a lot of movies info, each movie has a different id like "tt0202025".
I also have a file with the actors info and each one has an id like "mm2183122"
I have another file witch describes in which movie an actor is part of. mm2183122|tt0202025,tt0204548

I have found some things for csv like insertion but i am not able to create the relations file between the nodes before because of the data size.

Do i have to add first the movies nodes and the actors nodes and after the relationships between them? And how is possible to know which node id is created for every node to create the relationships? The data is a big.

i also read for Batch Insertion but i was not able to understand exactly how it work so i can write my code in java.

Wish that someone can guide me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution, as you pointed out, is to insert movies nodes and actor nodes, then create the relationships.

You can track the nodes using "mm2183122" and "tt0202025" as properties on the nodes: for instance you'd have an "file_id" property on your nodes that you index when you create the nodes and query it when you want to create a relationship. I'd use unique indexes for making sure you don't duplicate the nodes if you insert them several times. For REST API, you have the doc here: https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-unique-indexes

Cypher also allows you to create unique nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Talend Open Studio for Big Data - it has a Neo4j connector. The learning curve is quite steep but worth it.