# neo4j : batch import relations

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neography

I'm having trouble to import relationships in a graph.

Let's say I have a few hundreds unique,indexed users that are already created. Then I'd like to create about 120k nodes, each of them being linked to some user through a relationship.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to find a way to batch the import. I'm trying to perform this with the *neography* ruby gem, but as I'm very new with this environment I wouldn't mind using another way if needed.

What I tried :

```
@neo.batch(
  [:get_node_index, 'user', 'user_id', '1'], #attempt to get the node from index
  [:create_node, {"foo => 'bar'}],
  [:create_relationship, "has" , "{0}", "{1}"] 
) # => fails
```

,

```
@neo.batch(
  [:create_unique_node, "user", "user_id", "1"], #attempt to create or get the node
  [:create_node, {"foo" => "bar"}],
  [:create_relationship, "has", "{0}", "{1}"]
) # => fails.
```

Please note that it is nonetheless possible to batch some `create_unique_node` commands alone.

The only way I could get the script run is to use

```
@neo.batch(
  [:create_node, {"user_id" => 1}], #works, but duplicates the node
  [:create_node, {"foo" => "bar"}],
  [:create_relationship, "has", "{0}", "{1}"]
) # => success
```

However, this will duplicate all my user nodes, which definitely not what I want to achieve.
It seems my question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971555/import-large-data-in-neo4j-without-knowing-the-node-id), however I don't get at all how am I supposed to use the index when creating the relationships.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: I actually used some workaround, I'll post an answer to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question has been upvoted I'm posting the workaround I found since then:

As mentionned in the question, it is possible to batch the `create_unique_node` to create the nodes. The `batch` command then returns a list of pointers in which you can get the neo4j ids of each node. I'm not sure to remember wether I had to extract the ids from some hash structure or not, but I'm sure you'll get the point.

So basically, I first created a batch and stored the result in an array :

```
ids = @neo.batch(
    # list of `create_nodes` commands
) #=> returns a list of neo4j ids that you can use further.
```

To link the nodes, I used a second batch command. Instead of using the failing `{id}` reference, you can simply use the (absolute) neo4j id of the nodes, so this would look like

```
[:create_relationship, "something", id1, id2]
```

where `id1` and `id2` are given by `ids`.

This is basically a solution where I'm using absolute ids rather than relative ones....